# Multiple webcam displayed on buttons in a tkinter GUI

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI with tkinter where several buttons would display a video feed from several webcams. Clicking on those buttons would then select a feed to display in a larger frame.
I am puzzled because even if my code theoretically works, the entire thing just freeze and/or crashes.

Did anyone ever succeeded at something similar ?
I fail to find examples.

Here is the pertinent part of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

win= tkinter.Tk(screenName=None,  baseName=None,  className='Main',  useTk=1)

def webcam0():
    video_cam_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not video_cam_0.isOpened():
        labelcamone = tkinter.Label(labelcamchoice, text="1", relief=tkinter.GROOVE, font=('','44'),background="red", foreground="black", anchor='n')
        labelcamone.place(relx=0.005,rely=0.005,relwidth=0.15,relheight=0.3, anchor="nw")
        labelcamone = tkinter.Label(labelcamone, text="offline",font=('arial italic','22'), background="red", foreground="black")
        labelcamone.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM)
        print("Webcam is off")
    while(video_cam_0.isOpened()):
        ret0, cam0 = video_cam_0.read()
        if ret0:
            camoneimg = cv2.cvtColor(cam0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            video1img = Image.fromarray(camoneimg)
            imgtkone = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = video1img)
            webcamone = tkinter.Button(labelcamchoice, image = imgtkone)
            webcamone.place(relx=0.005,rely=0.005,relwidth=0.15,relheight=0.3, anchor="nw")
        if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord('q'):
            break
    video_cam_0.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

webcam0()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move this webcam0() to outside of mainloop()

Comment: @toyotaSupra This solved the freezing problem! However the webcam0 function does nothing now. Still investigating, but thanks!

Comment: where did you get the (labelcamchoice.....    tkinter.Button(labelcamchoice?

Comment: @toyotaSupra It's just a frame I forgot to include in the code sample.